# connection 4 to mongodb.net:27017 closed

Tags: java, banco-de-dados

Estou aprendendo a mexer no MongoDB e do nada, esse "erro" começa a aparecer.
Alguém sabe como resolver?
Linguagem de programação que estou utilizando: Java

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver o problema. 
O motivo do problema era que eu estava fechando a conexão com o banco de dados logo após abri-lá.